# how to design a pattern in ruby and then subtract two design elements from each line

Tags: ruby

My teacher asked me create a diamond design from user input and i did:

```
def diamond
  puts "Please enter a number greater than 3 so we can create a diamond design for you."
  x =  gets.chomp.to_i
  y = x-1

 1.upto y do |n|
     print' ' * (x-n)
     puts "x " * n
 end

    puts"x " * x


  y.downto 1 do |n|
      print ' ' * (x-n)
     puts  "x " * n 
  end

end   

diamond
```

if you enter 5 you get:

```
    *
   * *
  * * *
 * * * *
* * * * *
 * * * *
  * * *
   * *
    *
```

But he said it was wrong, he said it should be like this:

```
   *
  ***
 *****
  ***
   *
```

the pattern i see here is that two stars are removed from the second line and two more for the top line leaving only one star I realized two things: 1. this pattern only works if the user enters an odd number and 2. i also noticed that the height for and odd number is user-input -1/2
My new code is:

```
def diamond
  puts "Please enter a number greater than 3 so we can create a diamond design for you."
  user_input =  gets.chomp.to_i
  y = user_input - 1
  z = (user_input - 1) / 2
  d= user_input - 2

 if user_input % 2 == 1
 1.upto z do |n|
  print' ' * (user_input-n)
  puts "x "  * n
end
 end
# puts"x " * user_input

=begin
  y.downto 1 do |n|
      print ' ' * (x-n)
     puts  "x " * n 
  end
=end
end
diamond
```

But i only get

```
   *
  * *
```

it should be

```
    *
  * * *
```

Comment: In your first version, you can add `if n.odd?` to ALL `print` and `puts` statements - e.g. `print ' ' * (x-n)  if n.odd?`.  That should give you the pattern the way you wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to print `2*n-1`asterisks.

Suppose the user enters the odd number `n` for the maximum number of stars in a line, which also equals the number of lines to be printed. Let me refer to the lines to be printed as `"line 0"`, `"line 1"`,..., `"line n-1"`. Then:

- if `nspaces` and `nstars` equal the number of spaces and stars in a given line, `nspaces + nstars + spaces = n`, or `2*nspaces + nstars = n`. Since `n` is given, `nspaces` can be computed from `nstars`, or vice-versa.
- the line `all_stars_line = (n-1)/2` is the line that has all stars. For example, if `n #=> 5`, `all_stars_line #=> 2`. (Since `n` is odd, this could also be written `all_stars_line = n/2`.)
- the number of stars in line `i` equals `n` for `i == all_stars_line` and is reduced by `2` for each line offset deviation from `all_stars_line`: `nstars = n - 2*(i-all_stars_line).abs`. If `n #=> 5`, this equals `5` for line `i=2` (deviation of `0`), `3` for lines `1` and `3` (deviation of `1`) and `1` for lines `0` and `4` (deviation of `2`).
- the number spaces in line `i` therefore equals `(n-nstars)/2`.

We can now write down the code that implements the above.

```
n = 13
all_stars_line = (n-1)/2
n.times do |i|
  nstars = n-2*(i-all_stars_line).abs
  nspaces = (n-nstars)/2
  puts "%s%s" % [' '*nspaces, '*'*nstars]
end
      *
     ***
    *****
   *******
  *********
 ***********
*************
 ***********
  *********
   *******
    *****
     ***
      *
```